# Save on localstorage appended checkbox state

Tags: javascript, checkbox, append, local-storage

I have this function:

```js
function test() {
    var a = document.getElementById('test');
    var b = document.createElement('input');
    b.type = 'checkbox';
    b.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       //do something and save the state (checked)
    } else {
       //do something else and save the state(not checked)
    }
}
```

and I want to save the state of the checkbox on localstorage from the appended checkbox, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

Setting storage :

```
localStorage.setItem('checkbox', b.checked);
```

Getting storage :

```
var checkVal=localStorage.getItem('checkbox');
```

Comment: And how would I load get it?

Comment: It is similar like setItem, here you have to use localStorage.getItem('checkbox');

Comment: it doesnt work like that i think, Im appending it, so im making multiple checkbox
And it doesnt work anyways, i alredy tried like that

Comment: @Gabriel maybe you can create an array of objects having all values of checkboxes that can set to localStorage like localStorage.setItem("checkboxlist", JSON.stringify(checkboxlist));

Answer (score 0):

so if you are appending multiple checkboxes and you want to probably set all of their data separately you are going to need to have a different id for each checkbox so when you append a new one I would increment the ids

```js
//function that appends new checkbox

var i = 0;
function appendCheckBox(){
    i++
    checkBoxId = 'checkbox' + i;
    document.getElementById('checkbox-container').innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" id="${checkBoxId}" onclick="handleCheckBoxClick(this)"></input>`;
}

//function to handle checkbox click you would probably want to make it check if 
//the checkbox is already checked if it is set value to unchecked

function handleCheckBoxClick(ev){
    var checkBoxId = ev.id;
    localStorage.setItem(checkBoxId, 'checked')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a bit of work. `localStorage` [doesn't work in a snippet here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets), so a working example of the example code can be found [@ this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/5v63m2kd/)

```
localStorage.setItem("Checkboxes", "{}");
const showCurrentCheckboxStates = () => 
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = `Checkboxes saved state ${
    JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Checkboxes")), null, " ")}`;
const saveCheckboxState = (val, id) => {
  localStorage.setItem("Checkboxes", 
      JSON.stringify({
        ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Checkboxes")),
        [`Checkbox ${id}`]: val })
      );
  showCurrentCheckboxStates();
};
const createCheckbox = id => {
  let cb = document.createElement('input');
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cb.dataset.index = id;
  cb.title = `Checkbox ${id}`;
  document.body.appendChild(cb);
  // save the initial state
  saveCheckboxState(0, id);
};

document.addEventListener("click", evt =>
  evt.target.dataset.index && 
    saveCheckboxState(+evt.target.checked, evt.target.dataset.index)
);

for (let i = 1; i < 11; i += 1) {
  createCheckbox(i);
}
```

Comment: @Gabriel Sorry to hear that, maybe you should recheck the code you use. I am certain the JSFiddle works, I added reporting of the raw `localStorage` values to it

Comment: looks impressive and all, but i still would not know how to use it on my function, i want to save the check on the if statement and on else uncheck and save. I was able to to set it on localstorage, but it wasnt loading the checked state.

Comment: @Gabriel the code I supplied is to give you some direction. Stackoverflow is not meant to make people write the code for you.

Comment: ...I didnt ask for the code handed over to me, but what I was trying to say is that your code  didnt give me any directions, but leave me with more questions. Anyways thank you for your time.